# How can I draw a simple line?(OS X)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2

I tried this:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var butt: NSButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
@IBAction func buttPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let myPath = NSBezierPath()
    myPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20))
    myPath.lineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    myPath.stroke()
}

}
```

It compiles and runs but doesn't draw anything when the button is clicked.
I tried setting the color: `NSColor.redColor().set()`, setting the width: `myPath.lineWidth = 20`  and using `NSPoint` instead of `CGPoint` but still the same thing happens. What is it that I'm missing?
Thank you for your answers in advance and sorry for the elementary question.

Comment: Not sure what you searched for, but try: "cocoa" "drawing" "example" "swift".  It got me many pages of examples.

Comment: Trying to draw directly in `viewDidLoad` (`myPath.stroke()`) makes no sense, because, as the error tells you, you have nowhere to draw _in_ (no "context").

Comment: "I AM drawing directly in viewDidLoad" And I'm telling you that that makes no sense. Don't do it.

Comment: You still have no context. You don't seem to be listening. I don't know where you want this line to _go_, and neither does the runtime. You have to tell it. You have to have a _place to draw in_ before you can draw.

Comment: @matt Well, how should I create a context? If you please post the correct code as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it inside `drawRect` (`NSView`):

```
import Cocoa

final class Line: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let myPath = NSBezierPath()
        myPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20))
        myPath.lineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        myPath.stroke()
    }
}

final class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let line = Line(frame: frame)
        view.addSubview(line)
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```